# How do I make java wait for input before assigning the input to a variable to avoid java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, class, object, java.util.scanner

I'm studying Java classes and I'm trying to create a code where the user inputs how many objects (in this case "cube") they want to create.

In my main class I have this code written

```
System.out.println("Enter the amount of objects you want to create");
Scanner objNumInput = new Scanner(System.in);
int objNum = objNumInput.nextInt();
objNumInput.close();
Cube cubes[] = new Cube[objNum];

for (int i = 0; i < objNum; i++){
  String cubeName = Cube.inputName();
  double cubeLength = Cube.inputLength();
  cubes[i] = new Cube(cubeName, cubeLength);
}
```

in my Cube class I have here:

```
public static String inputName(){
  String cubeName;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
  cubeName = input.nextLine();
  return cubeName;
}
public static double inputLength(){
  double cubeLength;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the length: ");
  cubeLength = input.nextDouble();
  return cubeLength;
}
```

When I run it, I can input the number of "cubes" I want to create. Then, it keeps throwing an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at Cube.inputName(Cube.java:40)
at Main.main(Main.java:88)
```

what's wrong?

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23191324/2886891

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not close your `Scanner`, it will close `System.in` as well.

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface

As I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) the reason why you close your `objNumInput` is that you want to use it in two different methods.

I would suggest you to pass the `Scanner` as input parameter into your methods `inputName` and  `inputLength`. Then you'll be able to reuse the same scanner without closing it in between.

```
public static String inputName(Scanner scanner){
    String cubeName;
    System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
    cubeName = scanner.nextLine();
    return cubeName;
}

public static double inputLength(Scanner scanner){
    double cubeLength;
    System.out.println("Enter the length: ");
    cubeLength = scanner.nextDouble();
    return cubeLength;
}    

...

System.out.println("Enter the amount of objects you want to create");
Scanner objNumInput = new Scanner(System.in);
int objNum = objNumInput.nextInt();
//objNumInput.close(); <-- Do not close the scanner
Cube cubes[] = new Cube[objNum];

for (int i = 0; i < objNum; i++){
    String cubeName = Cube.inputName(objNumInput);
    double cubeLength = Cube.inputLength(objNumInput);
    cubes[i] = new Cube(cubeName, cubeLength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put objNumInput.close(); after for loop in your main method.The reason your program flashes by without pausing the second time because System.in is closed when you do objNumInput.close(); in the line number 3 of main method

- closing a Scanner object will close the underlying stream.
  -your code only works one time because System.in is getting closed. You cannot "open" System.in again. A closed stream cannot be reopened