# Recursively getting string user input with Scanner class in java

Tags: java, string, user-input

So, I want to receive input from the user, check if they used alphabetical values and then check if it is too long. If too long, I want to start again from the top (checking if alphabetical) by calling the method I am in. However, when I start over and I type, say "Danny", this will show:

> Output: "Thank you, got Danny"
> Output: (length of previous, too long input) + "is too many characters, try to keep it under 30."

So somehow, it keeps the original input (that was alphabetical, but above 30) saved and it doesn't alter it when it starts over. Anyone know what I should do instead?

```java
public static String inputPattern() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String player;
    int strLength;

    System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
    while (!scanner.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) { //Checks if alphabetical value
        System.out.println("Please stick to the alphabet!");
        scanner.next();
    }
    player = scanner.next();
    player += scanner.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + player);

    strLength = player.length(); // Saves the length of user-inputted name
    while (strLength > 30) { // Checks if not too long
        System.out.println(strLength + " is too many characters, please try to keep it under 30");
        inputPattern(); // Starts over again if too long
    }

    return player;
}
```

Comment: Your call of  `inputPattern();` in the method itself doesn't  save the return value of that call. so it will be discarded. either assign the return value to your player variable or directly return it. That being said, i wouldn't recommend recursive method calls to deal with wrong input. a simple loop would be a better fit to catch and handle wrong user input.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23322807/6309111 . It has pretty easy way of handling your situation with very less code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your method and modified it a bit.

It is non recursive solution.

Also in your code scanner resource was not closed at the end.

**Iterative Solution**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO66064473 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inputPatternIterative();
    }

    public static String inputPatternIterative() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String player = "";
        int strLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        while (strLength > 30) {                     // Checks if not too long
            System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
            while (!scanner.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {             //Checks if alphabetical value
                System.out.println("Please stick to the alphabet!");
                scanner.next();
            }
            player = scanner.next();
            player += scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + player);
            strLength = player.length();       // Saves the length of user-inputted name
            if (strLength > 30)
                System.out.println(strLength + " is too many characters, please try to keep it under 30");
        }
        scanner.close(); // Closing scanner resource after use.
        return player;
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Please enter your name:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Thank you! Got aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
70 is too many characters, please try to keep it under 30
Please enter your name:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa12
Please stick to the alphabet!
coifvoifoivmrfvoirvoirovroijfoirjfoijroifjrwofjorwfouwrfoijwrofjworjfoiwrjf
Thank you! Got coifvoifoivmrfvoirvoirovroijfoirjfoijroifjrwofjorwfouwrfoijwrofjworjfoiwrjf
75 is too many characters, please try to keep it under 30
Please enter your name:
Danny
Thank you! Got Danny
```

**EDIT : with the suggestion made by @Dev-vruper here is updated easy recursive code**

**Recursive Solution**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO66064473 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputPatternRecursive(sc);
        sc.close();
    }

    public static String inputPatternRecursive(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
        String player = sc.nextLine();
        if (!player.matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
            System.out.println("Please stick to the alphabet!");
            inputPatternRecursive(sc);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + player);
            if (player.length() > 30) {
                System.out.println(player.length() + " is too many characters, please try to keep it under 30");
                inputPatternRecursive(sc);
            }
        }
        return player;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was incredibly helpful! The only reason I didn't close the scanner yet is because it currently causes an exception. Even though a different method doesn't.

Comment: This will help you understand why you were getting exception after closing scanner as you might have put it inside recursive program and there are pitfalls to it https://stackoverflow.com/a/23191382/8017666

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem in a pretty easy way:

```
public static String inputPattern(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String player = "";
    int strLength;
    boolean bShowedInstruction = true;

    System.out.println("Please enter your name:");

    while (true) {
        if (!bShowedInstruction)
            System.out.println("Please enter your name:");

        bShowedInstruction = false;
        player = scanner.next();

        if (!player.matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
            System.out.println("Please stick to the alphabet!");
        }
        else if (player.length() > 30) {
            System.out.println(player.length() + " is too many characters, please try to keep it under 30!");
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + player);
    return player;
}
```

There's no need for a recursion. A simple while(true) loop does the trick.
It's a pretty clean solution keeping unnecessary scan-methods out of the game.